# Rewrite rule apache htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule that redirects only when the variable action is empty to the website index like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action= [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ / [L]
```

Access to file.php should redirect to / and file.php?action=value should not redirect.

But it's not working, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action= [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php / [NC,L,R]
```

That works if you test the presence of the variable `action`.

If you need to test the presence of the empty variable, use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php / [QSD,NC,L,R]
```

[QSD] work only since Apache 2.4.0. If it's not your case, use:

```
RewriteRule ^file\.php /? [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: None of them are working for me, don't know if it's because I use Apache 2.4 event mpm

Comment: I add `RewriteEngine on`. What is the result or the problem? That work well here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Yes, I think I have a problem with the compilation of the apache2 modules, thank you for the rule!